# rails overwrite nested attributes update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this model Person

```
class Person
 generate_public_uid generator: PublicUid::Generators::HexStringSecureRandom.new(32)

 has_many :addresses, as: :resource, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, allow_destroy: true, update_only: true,
                                        reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs[:content].blank? }
end
```

in my person table, I have this public_id that is automatic generated when a person is created.
now the nested attribute in adding addresses is working fine. but the update is not the same as what nested attribute default does.
my goal is to update the addresses using public_id

```
class Address
    generate_public_uid generator: PublicUid::Generators::HexStringSecureRandom.new(32)
    
    belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end
```

this is my address model

```
 { person: { name: 'Jack', addresses_attributes: { id: 1, content: 'new@gmail.com' } } }
```

this is the rails on how to update the record in the nested attribute

```
 { person: { name: 'Jack', addresses_attributes: { public_id: XXXXXXXX, content: 'new@gmail.com' } } }
```

I want to use the public_id to update records of addresses, but sadly this is not working any idea how to implement this?

Comment: In `{ person: { name: 'Jack', addresses_attributes: { id: 1 content: 'new@gmail.com' } } }` a comma is missing. Probably a typo but...

Comment: @Fravadona I already update it thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using both a "normal" id and "public" id? Would using the public id as primary key be a problem? If you use a random string as primary key Rails would automatically adapt and use those for the nested attributes. What database do you use? PostgreSQL offers uuid as data type, [which could be used for primary keys](https://pawelurbanek.com/uuid-order-rails).

Comment: yes I will use public id as a primary key

Comment: @3limin4t0r i use Postgres

Comment: @3limin4t0r I use public id to render my serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are using your `public_id` as primary key I assume you don't mind dropping the current numbered id. The main advantage of not using an auto increment numbered key is that you don't publicly show record creation growth and order of records. Since you are using PostgreSQL, you could use a UUID is `id` which achieves the same goal as your current `PublicUid::Generators::HexStringSecureRandom.new(32)` (but does have a different format).

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` uses the primary key (which is normally *id*). By using UUIDs as data type for your *id* columns, Rails will automatically use those.

I've never used this functionality myself, so I'll be using [this article](https://pawelurbanek.com/uuid-order-rails) as reference. This solution does not use the `public_uid` gem, so you can remove that from your Gemfile.

Assuming you start with a fresh application, your first migration should be:

```sh
bundle exec rails generate migration EnableExtensionPGCrypto
```

Which should contain:

```rb
def change
  enable_extension 'pgcrypto'
end
```

To enable UUIDs for all future tables create the following initializer:

```rb
# config/initializers/generators.rb
Rails.application.config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record, primary_key_type: :uuid
end
```

With the above settings changes all created tables should use an UUID as id. Note that references to other tables should also use the UUID type, since that is the type of the primary key.

You might only want to use UUIDs for some tables. In this case you don't need the initializer and explicitly pass the primary key type on table creation.

```rb
def change
  create_table :people, id: :uuid, do |t|
    # explicitly set type uuid ^ if you don't use the initializer
    t.string :name, null: false
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

---

If you are not starting with a fresh application things are more complex. **Make sure you have a database backup when experimenting with this migration.** Here is an example (untested):

```rb
def up
  # update the primary key of a table
  rename_column :people, :id, :integer_id
  add_column :people, :id, :uuid, default: "gen_random_uuid()", null: false
  execute 'ALTER TABLE people DROP CONSTRAINT people_pkey'
  execute 'ALTER TABLE people ADD PRIMARY KEY (id)'

  # update all columns referencing the old id
  rename_column :addresses, :person_id, :person_integer_id
  add_reference :addresses, :people, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true, null: true # or false depending on requirements
  execute <<~SQL.squish
    UPDATE addresses
    SET person_id = (
      SELECT people.id
      FROM people
      WHERE people.integer_id = addresses.person_integer_id
    )
  SQL

  # Now remove the old columns. You might want to do this in a separate
  # migration to validate that all data is migrating correctly.
  remove_column :addresses, :person_integer_id
  remove_column :people, :integer_id
end
```

The above provides an example scenario, but should most likely be extended/altered to fit your scenario.

---

I suggest to read the full [article](https://pawelurbanek.com/uuid-order-rails) which explains some additional info.

Comment: @DeezNuuts In the end `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is just a helper/generator method that generates the setter `addresses_attributes=` for your model. [These are hard-coded to use the `id`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/85c6823b77b60f2a3a6a25d7a1013032e8c580ef/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L391-L521). You can also use [`self.primary_key = 'public_uid'`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key-3D) in your models. (1/2)

Comment: You do still have to write a large migration, because that breaks all your current associations. Another option would be to write your own `accepts_nested_attributes_for` helper, which uses `public_uid` instead of `id`. You then also have to write your own `fields_for` form builder helper, which passes these. All of these solutions are quite a lot of work. (2/2)

Comment: actually i store id and public id

Comment: @DeezNuuts That is the reason this is so difficult. The associations are based on the *id*, yet you want to supply *public_id* from the user interface. If you would use one or the other things would be a lot simpler.

Comment: yes, I will consider your answer. I will find another way. your answer will be my last option thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rails generally assumes that you have a single column named `id` that is the primary key. While it is possible to work around this, lots of tools in and around Rails assume this default – so you'll be giving yourself major headaches if you stray from this default assumption.

However, you're not forced to use integer `id`s. As someone else has already pointed out, you can change the type of the ID. In fact, you can supply any supported type by doing `id: type`, where `type` can e.g. be `:string` in your case. This should then work with most if not all of Rails' default features (including nested attributes) and also with most commonly used gems.

Comment: yes i will use the public id as a primary key to update in nested attribute

Answer (score 0):

Because you still need an **:id** field in your params, unless you want to change your `to_param` directly in model. Try something like this:

```
person  = Person.first
address = person.address
person.update({ name: 'Jack', adddresses_attributes: { id: address.id, public_id: XXX, _destroy: true } } )
```

Comment: I cant use the address id rather I will use a public id

Comment: just to recap your tables have an id and a public_id. and the join or associations are on the public_id?

Comment: there is no join table cuz I'm using polymorphic

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I have my nested-attributes

```
#app/models/person.rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  ...
end
```

my controller

```
#app/controllers/people_controller.rb
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
   ...
   def update
     @person = Person.find_by(id: params[:id])
     if @person.update(person_params)
       redirect_to person_path, notice: 'Person was successfully added'
     else
       render :edit, notice: 'There was an error'
     end
   end
   ...
   private
   def person_params
     params.require(:person).permit(
        ... # list of person fields
        addresses_attributes: [
          :id,
          :_destroy,
          ... # list of address fields 
        ]
     )
   end
   ...
end
```

I hope that this is able to help you.

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: im not using the id but the public id.